# Image map selection in svg

Tags: javascript, svg

I am putting together an interactive for a biology project. I want to have the user click on a hyperlinked area of an image to link to more information. I am excited by SVGs because selections can be linked directly to the path without creating an image map overlay.

I used Illustrator to create the SVG and assigned a link to the path in the Attributes panel, but I was disappointed that the link is not active in the browser.
[image]
Here is that SVG: http://nspowers.org/bio/flower.html.

Next, I tried ImageMapster. I referenced the US map example (http://jsfiddle.net/juvyh/)

```
 $('img').mapster({
 mapKey: 'state'
 });
```

to generate this:

```
<img src="http://nspowers.org/bio/flower.svg" 
usemap="#usa" style="width:202px;height:151px;">
<map id="usa_image_map" name="usa">

<area href="#" state="stamen" full="Flower Identification" shape="poly" coords="103.709,42.484 96.906,45.624 92.981,55.306 94.551,65.249 102.663,70.482 115.484,72.314 120.979,66.557 122.025,57.399 120.194,50.596 125.165,60.539 126.735,67.604 123.072,78.07 114.437,83.042 113.391,84.874   99.892,86.705 85.916,78.594 80.421,69.436 77.281,59.231 81.468,49.026 90.103,42.484 95.598,39.868">
```

here: http://jsfiddle.net/nspowers/juvyh/1971 using the Illustrator SVG code.

I do not understand why the selection area is different from the shading-on-hover.
[image]

I would appreciate learning the cause of this difference and if there is a better workflow to achieve  paths that can be hyperlinked directly within the SVG that will display in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the `fill="none"` attribute on the polygon is what is suppressing the link.
If you change that to `fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.0)"` (fully transparent black) the link works fine.

Here is a jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/FE9LD/

And here is a jsfiddle with some css to add in the highlight effect (may need latest chrome): http://jsfiddle.net/FE9LD/1/

Comment: this is exactly what I was desiring to achieve. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you set `pointer-events="fill"` it will use the fill area as a link no matter what the value of `fill` is.

```
<a xlink:href="http://nspowers.org/flower-desc.jpg" >
    <polygon fill="none" pointer-events="fill" points="103.709,42.484 96.906,45.624 92.981,55.306 94.551,65.249 102.663,70.482 115.484,72.314 
        120.979,66.557 122.025,57.399 120.194,50.596 125.165,60.539 126.735,67.604 123.072,78.07 114.437,83.042 113.391,84.874 
        99.892,86.705 85.916,78.594 80.421,69.436 77.281,59.231 81.468,49.026 90.103,42.484 95.598,39.868       "/>
</a>
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/FE9LD/2/)

Comment: Thank you for adding this @BigBadoboom. This is good to learn and will help make the selections operate better.